Nim-like game from Swedish math competition
Question:
Alice and Bob are playing the following game: There are exactly 1000 pebbles in a pile in front of them. They take turns in taking either 1, 3, 4 or 16 pebbles. The player who takes the last pebble(s) is the winner of the game. Alice starts.
Is there a strategy which one of the player can use to guarantee their victory? And in that case, who is going to win with that strategy?
No caluclator nor digital tools were allowed, just pen and paper.
Background of the problem
This is a Nim-like game with the twist that the amount of pebbles you can take is arbitrary (they are not related to be clear). The question was asked in a Swedish math competition, which was in teams of four, and this was the third and one of the more difficult problems of the six. No solutions were handed out afterwards and my team did not find the winners to discuss with them. Any pertaining help or knowledge about the problem is appreciated.
My solution/attempt
(Disclaimer: this is purely my own attempt which no one has proofread yet, and I am not sure if this is the right way to tackle the problem.) Anyhow:
We start by writing down the different amount of pebbles there could possibly be and if it is a winning or losing position.
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccc}
0 &  1  & 2 &  3  & 4   & 5  & 6   & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 &  18 \\
L & W & L & W & W & W & W & L & W &L & W & W & W  & W  & L  &  W  & W  & W & W
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccc}
19 &  20  & 21 &  22  & 23   & 24  & 25   & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 &  37 \\
L & W & L & W & W & W & W & L & W &L & W & W & W  & W  & L  &  W  & W  & W & W
\end{array}
(I did calculate more positions but for the length of this post's sake I would rather not write out all of them here.)
To actually make this W/L board, we iterate through them:

To calculate these positions you start from $P_0$, which is a losing position because when it is your turn there are no pebbles left, which implies that the opponent took the last pebble last turn.
In $P_1$ you take one pebble and win.
In $P_2$ your only choice is to take one pebble and give the opponent the winning position $P_1$.
In $P_3$ you take one and put your opponent in the losing position $P_2$ which makes $P_3$ a winning position.

You always want to put your opponent in a losing position. This process is repeated for the positions up to e.g $P_{50}$.
This board of positions was found repeating for every 19th position (the reason for me putting 19 positions in every row on the board above.) This leads to the statement:
$$P_n = P_{n \pmod{19}}$$
So to put it shortly, every position corresponds to one of the first 19th positions. Knowing this, you always want to ensure that your opponent recieves a position $P_n$ such that $P_{n \pmod{19}} = L$. Those positions are $P_0, P_2, P_7, P_9$ and ${P_{14}}$ (every position from the first row of 19 that loses.)
So back in the game, there are 1000 pebbles. If the stack after taking either (1, 3, 4 or 16) $\equiv$ (0, 2, 7, 9 or 14)$\pmod{19}$ Alice is the winner. Otherwise Bob wins.
$1000 - 1 = 999$ which is $\equiv{11} \pmod{19}$, Losing position 
$1000 - 3 = 997$ which is $\equiv{9} \pmod{19}$, Winning position (Alice wins) 
$1000 - 4 = 996$ which is $\equiv{8} \pmod{19}$, Losing position 
$1000 - 16 = 984$ which is $\equiv{15} \pmod{19}$, Losing position 
$\therefore$ $\boxed{\text{Alice wins with this strategy.}}$
Questions:
So to summarize:

Is my attempt correct or is there any logical/trivial mistake?
Why is the pattern repeating every 19th position? Is it because of 16 + 3, and in that case why?
Is there any other better way to approach this problem? (as my way felt relatively tedious)
Is there any way to generalize these types of problems?


Your approach is a good one.  These games are discussed in Winning Ways vol 1.  As I remember, these games seem (though they did not say there was a proof) to enter a repeating pattern of W,L though there may be an initial segment that does not fit the pattern.  I don't think there was any easy relation between the numbers that could be removed and the length of the repeat.  Once you find the repeat, assuming it is longer than the maximum number you can take, you can prove it continues by induction.

This is an example of a subtraction game with a finite subtraction set (played according to the normal play convention).
For such a game with maximum possible subtraction of $16$, you were guaranteed an eventual periodic pattern of length at most $2^{16}$ (maybe there are better bounds), but it's not uncommon to have a much shorter period, and the competition probably intentionally chose $\{1,3,4,16\}$ because it worked out nicely.
Not too much is known about periods in general when the subtraction set has more than three elements like this, but maybe some paper has a result about $\{1,x,x+1,y\}$ (there are many special-case results).
There is probably no better approach than the sort of solution you came up with, except to note that you didn't really have to check all the way up to $50$ once you saw that the $19$ values repeated, since the largest subtraction is only $16$.
